# Creating video with audio and still image for YouTube

Tags: video, mp3, youtube, ffmpeg

I'm running the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -ar 44100 -f image2 -i logo.jpg -r 15 -b 1800 -s 640x480 foo.mov
```

Which successfully outputs a video with my recorded audio and an image on it.

When I try and upload this to YouTube it fails to process, regardless of the formats I try: .mov, .avi, .flv, .mp4

Is there some setting I'm missing in the above that would generate a format Youtube will accept? I've tried looking through the ffmpeg documentation but I'm in over my head.

I did an experiment by putting a 2 second video with a 30 second mp3. When I uploaded to youtube, the resulting video was only 2 seconds long. So it may be that YouTube looks only to the video track for the length, and since a picture is only a frame long or whatever, maybe that borks it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's what worked:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -f image2 -loop 1 -i logo.jpg 
-r 15 -s 640x480 \
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 -tune stillimage -preset medium \
-shortest foo.mov
```

Specifically, the `loop` option, which will duplicate the image as frames. It will also then need the `shortest` option to keep the file from growing and growing (this way it truncates it to the length of the shortest stream – here, the audio file).

The `r` option changes the frame rate, and `crf 18` sets the quality (use a higher value here for lower video quality). See here for more details: [FFmpeg: The ultimate Video and Audio Manipulation Tool](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get an one-frame movie.

Comment: I does work for me now.

Comment: works but is terribly slow, speed about 1x. encoding stillimage to video should take zero seconds, so it should have the same speed as copy. see also: [Speed Up FFMpeg Still Image to Video](https://superuser.com/questions/1417579/speed-up-ffmpeg-still-image-to-video-or-other-software)

Answer (score 5):

A piece of code that works for me, from another forum:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r ntsc -i image.jpg -i song.mp3 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset fast -threads 0 -shortest output.mkv
```

Answer (score 4):

I took Pavel's code, that worked for me too, and shortened it by trimming needless options:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -shortest -i <audio file> -i <image file> <output video file>
```

this is a general form that works with any image and audio file as input and produce a video file as output.

That said, since your video stream will be made of a single picture repeated indefinitely, you could set a low frame rate (that is the number of images that appears in a second) with `-r`. Note that not all output containers allow low frame rates. One that does is `avi`, so you might do:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -shortest -r 0.1 -i <audio file> -i <image file> output.avi
```

this would create a video file with a frame rate of 0.1 (i.e. one image each 10 seconds) instead of the default of 25. This will affect file size but not video quality. Eventually, you can set the audio bitrate to get a better audio quality with `-ab`. This is the command I actually use to make this kind of videos for youtube:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -shortest -r 0.1 -i <audio file> -i <image file> -ab 128k output.avi
```

Comment: Thanks. I ran `ffmpeg -loop 1 -shortest -r 0.1 -i audio.mp3 -i image.jpg output.avi` but got 'Option loop not found.' Any ideas?

Comment: @col If you're still interested: you need the loop option before the image input, not before the audio.

Comment: this is what worked for me: `ffmpeg -i <audio file> -loop 1 -i <image file> -shortest <output video file>`

Answer (score 1):

with avconv:

```
avconv -i input.mp3 -loop 1 -f image2 -i logo.png -r 30 -s 640x480 -ab 128k -ar 44100 -ac 1 -ss 00:00:00.000 -t 01:02:03.123 foo.ogv
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser and thanks for your answer. Some more detail about what you are proposing and why would be helpful.

Comment: the response is because of ffmpeg is deprecated

Comment: No the ffmpeg project is ongoing. There was a dispute that lead to the deprecated message. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756

Comment: ah ok, anyway, another way to do the same with different application, specially for me, i usually forget how to do it with avconv ;)

Comment: This command didn't work for me. The video kept growing and growing. My mp3 was 50 minutes long, but video was 5+ hours long at the time I interrupted it.

Comment: user31494 add the following: `-ss 00:00:00.000 -t 01:02:03.123`. 
-ss is where to star and -t is how much time is going to be, in this case 1 hour, 2 minutues, 3 seconds and 123 miliseconds, good luck

Comment: Use the `-shortest` output options instead of manually declaring times (also, use `ffmpeg` instead of  `avconv` if possible).

Comment: Made a [bash script](https://gist.github.com/dallaylaen/46e29d748b2815937fd32846a998b9bc) in case anyone is interested

Answer (score 1):

To add something a little shorter, this worked for me:

`ffmpeg -i audio.wav -loop 1 -i image.png -shortest foo.flv`

The order of options is important.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work after much experimentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjlDT819Q3s

1. Convert image(s) to video as per https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images:

   `ffmpeg -framerate 1/20 -i png/img-%03d.png -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" png.mp4`

   Here I use several images and make them change every 20s.
2. Concatenate enough copies of the above video to span the duration of your audio as per https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate. Other solutions, like expecting `ffmpeg -i wav.wav -i png.mp4 youtube.mp4` to do the right thing, ended up being rejected by YouTube (also, players such as VLC are confused and cannot seek properly). My guess is that time positions need to be adjusted in the copies, which `ffmpeg` does not do, unless they are concatenated:

   `ffmpeg -f concat -i pngs.txt -c copy pngs.mp4`

   (where the file `pngs.txt` is hand-made to contain as many copies as needed: copies = audio length / video length)
3. Mix your audio with the video obtained in 2 as per https://www.virag.si/2015/06/encoding-videos-for-youtube-with-ffmpeg/:

   `ffmpeg -i pngs.mp4 -i wav.wav -shortest -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart youtube.mp4`

Now the file `youtube.mp4` should be accepted by YT.