# The fastest way to encode image+audio for Youtube from command line?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, video-encoding

I have an mp3 and image and I want to make a simple clip to upload onto Youtube. Is there a fast solution? If video formats are so bad designed, then maybe it is possible to use a prerendered video-only clip?

This works good except it takes as much time as the audio lasts:

`ffmpeg -loop_input -r ntsc -i "%IMAGE%"  -i "%AUDIO%" -r 1 -acodec copy -shortest -re -force_fps "%VIDEO%"`

This takes a second but results in a black screen video that is successfully played by a desktop video player but *not acceptable* by Youtube:

`ffmpeg -i "%IMAGE%"  -i "%AUDIO%" -acodec copy "%VIDEO%"`

Windows 7. Preserving audio quality is preferred over video quality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ffmpeg: Creating video for Youtube](http://superuser.com/questions/98980/ffmpeg-creating-video-for-youtube)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not provide the complete console output of your command I will give you an example using recent ffmpeg syntax:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.jpg -i input.mp3 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 18 -tune stillimage -c:a copy -shortest output.mkv
```

Change `medium` to `veryslow` if you're patient and see [FFmpeg: The ultimate Video and Audio Manipulation Tool](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/) for more information and examples on using libx264.

Comment: Thank you! It takes just 30 seconds now that is quite acceptable. But if someone know an 1-second way, please let me know.

Comment: Use a faster preset. Current presets (excluding placebo) are: ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow.