# Ffmpeg : Audio/Video mixing but no sound

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, debian

I'm trying to add an audio file to a video file generated from images with FFmpeg.

The command i am using on a Debian distrib is this one

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -i edit%0d.jpg outputName.mp4 -i Test.mp3
```

The video file is created but the audio is not working .

Output ::

```
> ffmpeg version 0.8.9-6:0.8.9-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  3 2013 00:54:50 with gcc 4.7.2
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
[image2 @ 0x2283b20] max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, image2, from 'edit%0d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:24.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 800x600 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
[mp3 @ 0x22d8840] max_analyze_duration reached
[mp3 @ 0x22d8840] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from 'Test.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:46.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #1.0: Audio: mp3, 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
[buffer @ 0x2287480] w:800 h:600 pixfmt:yuvj420p
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] profile Main, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] 264 - core 123 r2189 35cf912 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=0 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=0 open_gop=1 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.25 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '6953289.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuvj420p, 800x600 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=   24 fps= 16 q=17.0 Lsize=    1247kB time=23.00 bitrate= 444.1kbits/s
video:1246kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.079555%
frame I:1     Avg QP:14.91  size: 65650
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] frame P:23    Avg QP:14.94  size: 52587
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] mb I  I16..4: 11.8%  0.0% 88.2%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] mb P  I16..4: 29.8%  0.0% 60.5%  P16..4:  6.8%  0.2%  0.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 2.4%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 73.2% 58.6% 49.7% inter: 9.2% 8.0% 1.2%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] i16 v,h,dc,p: 56% 24%  6% 14%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 22% 12%  7%  7%  7%  7%  7%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] i8c dc,h,v,p: 60% 17% 13%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] Weighted P-Frames: Y:17.4% UV:17.4%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] ref P L0: 12.9%  8.0% 66.4% 12.8%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7d20] kb/s:425.05
```

On Windows it is working fine, i tried multiple scenarios but i can't seem to find the issue, maybe a codec problem ?

Thank you !

Update :

I manage to fix it this way:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -i edit%0d.jpg -i Test.mp3 -ar 44100 -strict experimental
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the video stream is mapped:

```
Output #0, mp4, to '6953289.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuvj420p, 800x600 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
Stream mapping:
Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
```

I'm pretty sure that you still have to specify there a bit rate and resolution.

Something similar has been done before: [Creating video with audio and still image for YouTube](https://superuser.com/questions/98980/creating-video-with-audio-and-still-image-for-youtube)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to fix it. See my update